# Cannot change palette colors for light mode with Material UI

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am trying to create a light/dark mode switch for my React app using Material UI but for some reason I cannot change the text color on light mode (it is black, and I'm trying to make it a dark green-ish color, the one from the last image). This is my code for this:

```
interface LayoutProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}

const createPalette = (mode: PaletteMode) => {
  return {
    palette: {
      mode,
      primary: { main: '#7fffd4' },
      text: {
        primary: mode === 'light' ? '#ff0000' : '#7fffd4',
      },
      background: {
        paper: mode === 'light' ? '#ff0000' : '#005636',
      },
    },
  };
};

const Layout = ({ children }: LayoutProps) => {
  const [mode, setMode] = React.useState<PaletteMode>('light');

  const colorMode = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      toggleColorMode: () => {
        setMode((prevMode: PaletteMode) =>
          prevMode === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light',
        );
      },
    }),
    [],
  );
  const theme = React.useMemo(() => createTheme(createPalette(mode)), [mode]);

  return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Header toggleColorMode={colorMode.toggleColorMode} themeMode={theme.palette.mode} />
        {children}
      </ThemeProvider>
  );
};
```

I should mention that those red HEX values for the `primary` and `paper` attributes do nothing (in case mode === 'light') but the other ones (after `:`) do work for the dark mode. Does anybody know what is the solution for this?

In light mode, it looks like this:
[image: Light mode]

And in dark mode, it looks like this:
[image: Dark mode]

I think this has something to do with it but can't figure out why it's black:
[image: Typography_actual]
I expected it to be like this (unchecked the color checkbox):
[image: Typography_expected]
Thank you!